# Changes in admin utils module in Django

Tags: django, admin

Recently I upgraded Django in my project from version 1.6.11 to version 1.8.7. Now I get an error in my accounts module. Piece of code and error:

```
from django.contrib.admin import util


self.add_fieldsets = (
    ( some_data ),
    ( some_data ),
)

...
obj.update({
    'fields': admin.util.flatten_fieldsets(self.add_fieldsets),
})
```

I get an error:

```
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    'module' object has no attribute 'util'
```

It's about this method admin.util.flatten_fieldsets(self.add_fieldsets)
Was there any changes in this method in Django 1.8.x?

Comment: Has it moved to `django.contrib.admin.utils`?... This looks like it could be the same method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`util` modules were renamed to `utils` in Django 1.7 ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.7/#util-modules-renamed-to-utils)).

To update your code for Django 1.7+, replace the import

```
from django.contrib.admin import util
```

with

```
from django.contrib.admin import utils
```

Then change the code to

```
obj.update({
    'fields': utils.flatten_fieldsets(self.add_fieldsets),
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The import path is `django.contrib.admin.utils` not `django.admin.utils`

so replace your import with -

```
from django.contrib.admin import utils
```